# Com Exception: Code = -2,146,777,998 Code meaning = Unknown error 0x800AC472.Why this error showing in console C-PLEX?

Tags: variables, optimization, resultset, decision-tree, cplex

Com Exception:  Code = -2,146,777,998   Code meaning = Unknown error 0x800AC472.Why this error showing in console C-PLEX?

Comment: Do you call an Excel application ?

Comment: excel file is used for data linking

Comment: The program with trouble is given in the picture